# Objective C protocols requiring the implementation of at least one of a set of methods

Tags: objective-c, protocols

In Objective C, protocol methods can be required or optional:

```
@protocol AProtocol

@required
-(void) aRequiredMethod;

@optional
-(void) anOptionalMethod;

@end
```

Is there an elegant way to say the object conforming to the protocol has to respond to at least one of a set of methods, my dream would be something like

```
@protocol AProtocol

@anyof
-(void) onePossibleMethod;
-(void) anotherPossibleMethod;

@optional
-(void) anOptionalMethod;

@end
```

EDIT:

This being (as far as I know), impossible, would there be a way to raise a compile time warning if a class declared as conforming to a given protocol made entirely of optional methods

```
@protocol AProtocol

@optional
-(void) onePossibleMethod;
-(void) anotherPossibleMethod;

@end
```

failed to implement at least one of them.

Comment: re: 'EDIT' not that I have seen. If you really want to automate this, you could use the objc runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a great way to express this in Objective-C. If you must do this, IMO the most idiomatic and least code-bloating way is something along these lines:

```
@protocol AProtocol

@required
- (SEL)methodToUse; // returns one of "onePossibleMethod" or "anotherPossibleMethod"

@optional
-(void) onePossibleMethod;
-(void) anotherPossibleMethod;
-(void) anOptionalMethod;

@en
```

Comment: I agree there is no great way, however I do like your solution in that it makes it "official" (i.e. other than comments/documentation) to developers unfamiliar with the code that although the three methods are optional, you do expect one of them to be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are working with ObjC, so you will need to exercise some restraint yourself:

```
@protocol MONAbstractDataProvider
@optional
- (void)anOptionalMethod;
@end

@protocol MONDataProviderA < MONAbstractProvider >
@required
- (void)onePossibleMethod;
@end

@protocol MONDataProviderB < MONAbstractProvider >
@required
- (void)anotherPossibleMethod;
@end
```

In that case, you'll have to do a `confromsToProtocol:` test at the callsite, rather than `respondsToSelector:` test for `onePossibleMethod` and `anotherPossibleMethod`. Then you pass `MONAbstractDataProvider` around. That can introduce some type safety, as long as you remember the rules, but it is really only slightly better than the customary approach.

So the client side would look like this:

```
- (void)update:(NSObject<MONAbstractDataProvider>*)provider
{
    if ([provider conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MONDataProviderA)]) {
        [(NSObject<MONDataProviderA>*)protocol onePossibleMethod];
    }
    else if ([provider conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MONDataProviderB)]) {
        [(NSObject<MONDataProviderB>*)provider anotherPossibleMethod];
    }
    else {
        assert(0 && "rule broken");
    }
}
```

That of course assumes the client knows about all of the derivatives.

You may instead prefer the simpler singular approach if they are both `void`:

```
@protocol MONAbstractDataProvider
@required
- (void)performPossibleMethod;
@optional
- (void)anOptionalMethod;
@end
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, this would be a way to do the check at run-time. Ideally what I would like is some kind of compile-time check that would raise a warning (I edited the question slightly).

Comment: @jbat100 hmm - i didn't make the detail of the approach very clear. the compile time check enters because `MONAbstractDataProvider` is only adopted *indirectly*. classes should only adopt `MONDataProviderA` or `MONDataProviderB`, never `MONAbstractDataProvider` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dynamic delegate property that only allows the delegate to be assigned to classes that implement one method or the other—but that'd be at runtime and not at compile time. You could also create a bash script that would check if one or the other was implemented and that'd be at compile time.